# curl login using php in asp.net website

Tags: php, asp.net, curl

I want PHP login script using curl call in my below asp.net website url

I have tried but in input type i cant find proper name for username and password so please tell me what i have exact write code

link is here

https://evend.tabarih.net/Security/SignIn.aspx

my sample code here

```
//username and password of account
$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";

//set the directory for the cookie using defined document root var
//$dir = DOC_ROOT."/ctemp";
//build a unique path with every request to store 
//the info per user with custom func. 
//$path = build_unique_path($dir);

//login form action url
 $url="https://example.net/Security/SignIn.aspx"; 
$postinfo = "email=".$username."&password=".$password;

//$cookie_file_path = $path."/cookie.txt";
$cookie_file_path = "cookie.txt";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
//set the cookie the site has for certain features, this is optional
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "cookiename=0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.0; en-US; rv:1.7.12) Gecko/20050915 Firefox/1.0.7");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postinfo);
curl_exec($ch);

//page with the content I want to grab
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.net/ProductsTBL/ShowProductsTBLGallery2.aspx");
//do stuff with the info with DomDocument() etc
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I think my issue will be I am sending parameter name which is different.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working correct. Whats the response you are getting from the curl

Just comment this line

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.net/ProductsTBL/ShowProductsTBLGallery2.aspx");
```

Because you already set the URL in the top.

I hope now it will work for you.

Comment: Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8080
Request URL:http://codeembassy.net/projects/curl/curl.php
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Response Headers
view source
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Fri, 31 Jul 2015 07:09:07 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.2.29 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.29 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.29                                                                                                           this is my request and response null nothing

Comment: please check the above answer. I have updated it now

Comment: yes commented this line and try to print response. it displayed below           HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: private Content-Length: 31775 Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 Set-Cookie: TEVendV1_RememberName=False; expires=Fri, 31-Dec-9999 23:59:59 GMT; path=/ Set-Cookie: TEVendV1_UserName=; expires=Fri, 31-Dec-9999 23:59:59 GMT; path=/ Set-Cookie: TEVendV1_RememberPassword=False; expires=Fri, 31-Dec-9999 23:59:59 GMT; path=/ Set-Cookie: TEVendV1_Password=; expires=Fri, 31-Dec-9999 23:59:59 GMT;